# Where mongoimport store the document in a Docker container

Tags: mongodb, meteor, docker

So I'm searching where the files are stored after this command

```
mongoimport --db meteor --collection articles --type csv --headerline --file /data/seeds/articles.csv
```

I'm using a Docker container from the image `mongo:latest`

I thought it would be in the `/data/db` but there isn't my db 'meteor' or my collection 'articles' so I think I'm not in the right folder...
(The application is working perfectly, the data are displayed on the website)

Someone can help me ?

Comment: its imported into your db collection articles. not stored anywhere. To view the collection article you have to launch mongo shell and run find query to view your data.

Comment: Thank you ! If you want put an answer do it I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[MongoImport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)*** imported the csv data into db collection articles.

You will now have to connect to mongod server through mongo shell and run the below commands.

Switch to the db meteor

```
Use meteor
```

View collection article

```
db.article.find()
```